Want to select only minutes and seconds in Flutter TimePicker
Is there any built in widget in 'material' flutter which allows us to select minutes and seconds in a rotating dial like manner, something similar to TimePicker widget (which only allows to select a particular time in hours and minutes).
I tried searching up on internet and flutter docs, but found nothing.

Seems like you've already found the answer with your research. If you want to add seconds to a picked time, I would suggest manually adding them using a DateTime format (Even though the the user will not be able to pick the seconds). But if you want to let the users pick, you have to do it manually or use a package. If you want to know how to add them manually I can help.

Please help with the manual one

Have you checked CupertinoTimerPicker?
It provides seconds in  mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hms,
CupertinoTimerPicker

I want my app to follow the material design theme, I had considered that option
